# Twitter no longer authorizes old Android devices / webview?

Tags: android, webview, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I noticed this when I re-ran my app on 2.2 and 2.3.4 devices. Basically I have a WebView which is loaded with twitter4j's client `getAuthenticationURL`. 
[image: Twitter Login]

If everything is correct and "Sign In" is clicked, webview will load another page asking for user's authorization. From there, "Authorize app" will return the app's custom callback and user tokens.

[image: Twitter Authorization]

**Clicking that "Sign In" button will no longer send the webview to the authorization page**. It will just stay there. When I debugged my WebViewClient and probed `onPageStarted`, I noticed that a request was sent. But there's just no response from Twitter. Also, **in my 4.4 Nexus tablet, there's no authorization page**. "Sign in" will both authorize and immediately return the callback.

So far I found three workarounds for it (all these tests were done from clean install):

- Click cancel, restart the app, and reload the same url + request token. This time there's no login. It will get webview to directly load the Authorization page.
- This is the complete hack of all. Basically I need to enter a wrong password and I will get sent to a Password reconfirm page. If I enter the right password this time, I will see that authorization page. In fact the second snapshot above was obtained this way.
- If I paste that url + request token on a browser, **it will also skip the authorization page** and immediately return my callback. I haven't made a thorough research if this works on startActivity-for-browser scheme, not embedded webview. 
  EDIT : it works, upon Sign In, browser will fire a warning and then return the callback which my app intercepts in onNewIntent. There is no authorization page. Also callback url needs to have callback host like bla://callback

  [image]

I am pretty sure I was able to navigate the login pages including authorization with my older devices not long ago. Is this authorization thing broken or obsolete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of better answer then the current solution will have to do: separate login methods. I use Intent to browser for pre-ICS and WebView for the rest.